# Tableau: Action button to extract activesheet to pdf

Tags: tableau-api

I want to add a button to a sheet that extracts the active sheet in tableau to pdf, does anyone know if that is possible in tableau 2019.3?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using Tableau Server? And do you mean active worksheet or active dashboard?

Comment: active dasboard.. or just a simple worksheet in that dashboard...